# Using Passenger 2.2.5, why am I getting the following error on my Ruby on Rails page about an unreferenced "/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, passenger

Running:
Apache 2.2.3
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.4
Passenger 2.2.5

Error message:

```
/var/www/derscheidfamily/app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '\n' or ';' 
def app/controllers 
        ^ 
/var/www/derscheidfamily/app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '\n' or ';' 
def app/helpers 
        ^ 
    Exception class: 
    SyntaxError 
    Application root: 
    /var/www/derscheidfamily
```

greetings_controller is as follows:

```
class GreetingsController < ApplicationController
  def hello
  end

  def exists
  end

  def app
  end

  def exists
  end

  def app/controllers
  end

  def exists
  end

  def app/helpers
  end

  def create
  end

  def app/views/greetings
  end

  def exists
  end

  def test/functional
  end

  def create
  end

  def app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb
  end

  def create
  end

  def test/functional/greetings_controller_test.rb
  end

  def create
  end

  def app/helpers/greetings_helper.rb
  end

  def create
  end

  def app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb
  end

end
```

Comment: The error message says "unexpected" not "unreferenced."  Unless you post your controller code, how is anyone supposed to know what you did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These are not valid Ruby method names.

```
def app/controllers
end

def app/controllers/greetings_controller.rb
end

# etc...
```

Aside from probably needing to read some documentation, I would strongly suggest that you run this in a clean Rails project:

```
./script/generate scaffold greetings
```

And then take a look at what it generates.  You can learn a lot about how a basic Rails app is structured that way.

Comment: Wow, that looks a lot more like code, all right!  I think I was trying to get too complicated with the original generate scaffolding.  Thanks!